# INT_MAX vs numeric_limits<int>::max()

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

Is numeric_limits::max() preferred over INT_MAX in C++ ? If so, what is the reason for this ?
What should be preferred in simple cases like finding minimum and maximum element in an array ?

Comment: @JamesRoot, I understood I need to use  numeric_limits::max() in C++ over INT_MAX, but I want to know the reason for this .

Comment: `INT_MAX` would be the old C way, defined through a preprocessor macro. `numeric_limits<int>::max()`, the replacement, is not preprocessor based but template based, a more idiomatic approach.

Comment: What has INT_MAX to do with findling maximum element?